# Minimising the surface area of a cone with a base

Tags: calculus

I solved this if the cone has no base but I cannot do it with a base and I need help.

My goal is to show $h = 2\sqrt{2}r$ and my attempt was $$\frac{dA}{dh}=\frac{d}{dh}\left(\pi r^2+\pi r\sqrt{r^2+h^2}\right)=\frac{d}{dh}\left(\pi \:r^2+\pi \:\sqrt{r^4+r^2h^2}\right),\:\text{where }r^{2\:}=\frac{3V}{\pi h}$$

I tried three times separately and failed to simplify it all three times. I then tried it a fourth time with respect to $r$ but that also failed. Why is this so hard?

For no base, there is a trick to simplify by squaring $A$ ($A$ is surface area, $V$ is volume), but here I'm not sure how to apply that trick. Is it an expansion of $(x+y)^2$? That doesn't simplify then because the square root remains.

The exact question working is:

> Show that a cone with a base of a given capacity will require the least amount of material when $h$ = $2\sqrt{2}r$.

Comment: I added the exact question. It is a show question

Comment: Something has to be fixed- $h,r,l$ or $\theta$

Comment: sorry, i should've specified the volume is fixed

Comment: Actually i did specify that. "a cone..with a given capacity"

Comment: If you showed us one of your attempts, it would most likely have been a sign error or something which would be easily noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: h=2√2r]

Hope I don't need to show $(\frac{d^2A}{dr^2})_{r=\frac{h}{2\sqrt{2}}}>0$ :)

Comment: mm pls type answers in latex

Answer (score 2):

Substituting in $r^2 = \frac{k}{\pi h}$ where $k = 3V$, we want to minimise:

$$\pi \frac{k}{\pi h}+\pi \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{\pi^2 h^2}+\frac{k}{\pi h} h^2} = \frac{k}{h} + \sqrt{k^2/h^2 + k \pi h}$$

Now differentiating with respect to $h$:

$$-\frac{k}{h^2} + \frac{-2k^2h^{-3} + k\pi}{2 \sqrt{k^2/h^2 + k \pi h}} = 0$$

$$\implies -h+\frac{-2k+\pi h^{3}}{2\sqrt{k^{2}/h^{2}+k\pi h}}=0 \tag{$h \ne 0$}$$

$$\implies 4k^{2}-4k\pi h^{3}+\pi^{2}h^{6}=4h^{2}\left(\frac{k^{2}}{h^{2}}+k\pi h\right)$$

$$\implies \pi^2 h^6 = 8k \pi h^3 \implies h^3 = \frac{8k}{\pi}$$

and since $k = r^2 \pi h$, $h^3 = 8r^2h$ or $h = 2 \sqrt{2}r$ since $h, r > 0$.

Comment: As to why this is the minimum, as $h \to 0^+$, the $k/h$ term and the $k^2/h^2$ inside the square root dominate and the surface area tends to infinity (which is true by visualising it). And as $h \to \infty$, the $k \pi h$ term dominates which tends to infinity.

Comment: Ah I really like the proof that it is a minimum  since it avoids finding the second derivative

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky and complicated, go through it step-by-step patiently. Note $\theta$ is angle from vertical axis of cone at the apex. First of all, $$\tan\theta=\frac{r}{h}; V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$ after rearranging a bit and eliminating $h$, $$\frac{3V}{\pi}=\frac{r^3}{\tan\theta}......(1)$$ and now as volume is constant, differentiating the above equation gives $$3dr\tan\theta=r\sec^2\theta d\theta......(2)$$ Now plugging in the formula of $$S.A=\pi r \sqrt {r^2+h^2}+\pi r^2, r=h\tan\theta$$ gives $$\pi(r^2+\frac{r^2}{\sin\theta})$$ now multiplying and dividing by $r$ and substituting value of $r^3$ from derived volume formula $..(1)$ gives $$S.A=\frac{3V}{r}(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)$$ Differentiating the above equation and equating it to zero for maximum area gives $$r\sec\theta=dr......(3)$$ Solving $(2)$ and $(3)$ gives $$3\tan\theta=\sec\theta$$ which gives $$\tan\theta=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt 2}\Rightarrow h=2\sqrt 2 r$$